# Spring Tool Suite doesn't show integration-graph for a spring-integration-context.xml file

Tags: spring, spring-integration, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a fully functional Spring Integration project.  I'm using Spring Tool Suite 3.5.1.  When I open my `spring-integration-context.xml` file I only get `Design` and `Source` for tabs at the bottom of the editor window.  I'm looking for `integration-graph` but cannot figure out how to enable it or show it.

On my work machine I'm using Spring Tool Suite 3.5.0 and I get `Source`, `Namespaces`, `Overview`, `beans`, `integration`, and `integration-graph` as tabs for the xml file.  Any ideas? Thanks~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the project and enable "Spring Nature".

Comment: And possibly right-click on the file and Open With the specific editor; sometimes Eclipse gets the association slightly wrong.

Comment: It was already enabled, but I disabled and then re-enabled and now it works, thank you!  Also, thank you for taking the time to field questions, it's really cool getting a response from the lead developer :D

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file and select "open with" -> "spring config editor"